# Is Facebook's client-side auth secure enough?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am considering facebook login for my site. Based on facebook based authentication, the user will be logged in to the site. And will continue to use it until he/she logs out from the site, irrespective of facebook login status. Like most of the other sites.

While looking into the FB's client-side login method, I notice that it's based on the signed_request data received from the fbsr_{app_id} cookie. And FB want's that to be exchanged for a valid short-lived access_token within 10 mins of it's issue, to validate the authentication request. (This 10 mins seems to be the best effort by FB to minimize the security hole.)

However, within this 10 mins, someone else can copy the cookie and without much difficulty, can make a successful attempt to login as the victim. This is a concern for me and would like to ask the following questions:

1. Am I missing something here regarding the security aspects of FB's client-side authentication or it indeed has this weakness?
2. Is there something I can do in my implementation to plug the gap, or is moving to FB's server-side authentication the only answer?

Comment: Assuming you're using HTTPS, what you're suggest is a security hole would be very difficult to exploit. The attacker would essentially need to sit down at the user's machine. But an "attacker" can always do that anyway if the user doesn't log out.  Or was there another way you were thinking that could be exploited?

Comment: You're looking at OAUTH 2.0 login workflow, yes?

Comment: @Madbreaks Yes, oauth2. And currently not using HTTPS. You really don't need to be on the victim's machine. In workplaces, you can always manage to get the cookie. 10 mins and some handy tools is a good time for that, I guess. (Well, I am not trying to be paranoid with security here, but trying to understand and choose the better option for this authentication).

Comment: @Madbreaks If the user doesn't logout, the 'attacker' doesn't get the fbsr_{uid} cookie if '"cookie":"false"' is set for FB.init().

Comment: @Ethan If you're not using HTTPS, then it doesn't matter how safe the FB auth is - the attacker could simply steal *your* cookies while the user is signed in and hijack the session.

Comment: @SeanKinsey HTTPS is not overlooked, will get in as I move forward in the project. Your point here is off topic. My query is regarding the security risks during the login phase using FB's client-side JS SDK, and not during the sustenance of authenticity and perils thereof. However, to touchbase your point, there are also methods to detect hijacked sessions when running without https.

Comment: Facebook uses OAuth to authorize access to identity data together with a signed_request (to add audience scoping), so yes, it is secure.

Comment: @SeanKinsey I am sorry but you haven't read the question. It's ok if you don't know the answer.

Comment: @Ethan, I'm commenting on this, not answering. And if I were to answer, I would probably know what I'm talking about as I've written much of the code involved :)

Comment: @SeanKinsey Good that you finally chose to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use the server side flow, or client side flow - they are both fully secure if used correctly.
As you mention, using the cookie option on a non-ssl based site is indeed a vulnerability, but this is one that is not controlled by Facebook.

If you want to avoid this attack vector altogether, don't use the cookie option, and instead pass the signed request from the frontend to the backend using your mechanism of choice, eg XHR over SSL. To do this, simply subscribe to the relevant events - your handler will then be called with the signed request as the part of the response.

The signed_request should always be validated on the server to avoid any tampering or spurious usage. The signed_request also contains the issued_at time and it should be validated to be within the last 10 mins. (For FB's user id, use the user_id provided with it).

Comment: Having the 10 mins lifetime of 'code' is not facebook's weakness or controller by fb. But facebook can definitely increase the security with client-side login approach.

Comment: You are suggesting to not have the fbsr cookie created, ie always run with cookie:false. Not having signed_request available to the other backend handlers (barring login) to work on will have immediate impacts like to increase the timeout period of server cache entries spiking the memory footprint or forcing the user to go through frequent login process increasing user frustration and instrumenting the handlers to have an ajax post on subsequent page visit increasing on transparent interactions with backend. The cost of this approach is more than the gain of working around the login weakness.

Comment: @SeanKinsley Your description on handling signed_request needed refinement. I have edited your post (last paragraph).